# Is it possible to use goroutines in hyperledger fabric chaincode?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, smartcontracts, chaincode

I am trying to perform multiple queries using shim.GetQueryResults API using goroutines simultaneously. But it's failing but when I do that normally without goroutines sequentially its working properly. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to use GetQueryResults inside a goroutine. Failed every time I tired. Also tried GetState inside GoRoutine. It failed as well.